# ¿Cómo hago para que un input file aparezca con un archivo preseleccionado?

Tags: php, html, html5

Estoy haciendo un `update` en una vista, estoy trayendo los datos de la base de datos e insertándolos en un `value` para mostrarlos al usuario. todo bien hasta que quiero que aparezca seleccionado un `input file`. Destacar que el dato de la imagen que quiero mostrar es el nombre del archivo que tengo almacenado en un directorio del proyecto.

¿Hay alguna función para que aparezca como seleccionado el `input file` con `php` o `html`?

```
 <form action="<?php echo RUTE_URL;?>/controllerItem/update" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="category">Seleccionar Categoria</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
                                <option value="basquetbol">Basquetbol</option>
                                <option value="futbol">Futbol</option>
                                <option value="outdoor">Outdoor</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Precio</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $dates['items']->price;?>" name="price" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="description">Descripcion :</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" rows="3" required><?php echo $dates['items']->description;?></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="image">Actualizar Imagen</label>
                            <input type="file" name="image" value="<?php echo RUTE_URL .'/public/img/' . $dates['items']->image;?>" class="form-control-file" id="image" aria-describedby="fileHelp" required>
                            <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Debe agregar una imagen deportiva.</small>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Actualizar Item</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Comment: no se si entendi bien, queres hacer el focus o hacer que el input de tipo `file` tenga un file seleccionado(cargado)

Comment: Si, quiero que aparezca cargado.

Comment: okay, lamentablemente por motivos de seguridad en el browser no es posible seleccionar archivos dinamicamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te refieres a tener un archivo pre-seleccionado en tu input me temo que no es posible por motivos de seguridad. Imagina que por defecto cargas un archivo llamado contraseñas.txt que se encuentre en el disco C y el usuario no se da cuenta. La única manera es que el usuario cargue el archivo por si mismo. En caso de que detectes que ya existe algo en la base de datos puedes quitar el `required` o no poner ese campo.

Un saludo y espero que sea de ayuda.